# Highlighting duplicate values

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008-r2

I have the following script:

```
   SELECT
   Reference.ReferenceNumber AS [Reference.ReferenceNumber)
   Reference.LastName
   Reference.FirstName
   Address.ReferenceNumber AS [Address.ReferenceNumber]
   Address.Address1
   Address.Address2
   Address.Address3
   Address.Address4
   Address.ZipCode
   Telephone.ReferenceNumber AS [Telephone.ReferenceNumber]
   Telephone.TelephoneNumber
   Email.ReferenceNumber AS [Email.ReferenceNumber]
   Email.EmailAddress
   FROM
   Reference
   INNER JOIN Address
   ON Reference.ReferenceNumber = Reference.ContactNumber
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Telephone
   ON Reference.ReferenceNumber = Telephone.ReferenceNumber
   LEFT OUTER Join Email
   ON Reference.ReferenceNumber = Email.ReferenceNumber
```

This pulls through all customers, plus their addresses, email and phone numbers.

However some have duplicate surnames and addresses.

Please can you advise an amendment to the script that would show which records were duplicates? Ideally I'd like the output to show where the surname, address 1 and the zipcode were identical and restrict the output to the duplicate rows only.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
SELECT
Reference.ReferenceNumber AS [Reference.ReferenceNumber),
case when vrln.c is null then Reference.LastName else 'dup: ' + Reference.LastName end as LastName, 
Reference.FirstName,
Address.ReferenceNumber AS [Address.ReferenceNumber],
Address.Address1,
Address.Address2,
Address.Address3,
Address.Address4,
Address.ZipCode,
Telephone.ReferenceNumber AS [Telephone.ReferenceNumber],
Telephone.TelephoneNumber,
Email.ReferenceNumber AS [Email.ReferenceNumber],
Email.EmailAddress
FROM
Reference
INNER JOIN Address
ON Reference.ReferenceNumber = Reference.ContactNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN Telephone
ON Reference.ReferenceNumber = Telephone.ReferenceNumber
LEFT OUTER Join Email
ON Reference.ReferenceNumber = Email.ReferenceNumber

left join (
    select rln.LastName, add.Address1, add.ZipCode, count(rln.LastName) as c
    from 
        Reference rln 
        INNER JOIN Address add
            ON rln.ReferenceNumber = add.ReferenceNumber
    group by rln.LastName, add.Address1, add.ZipCode 
    having count(rln.LastName) > 1
) vrln on Reference.LastName = vrln.LastName and Address.Address1 = vrln.Address1 and Address.ZipCode = vrln.ZipCode

where vrln.c is not null
```

but, to find duplicates :

```
select rln.LastName, add.Address1, add.ZipCode, count(rln.LastName) as c
from 
    Reference rln 
    INNER JOIN Address add
        ON rln.ReferenceNumber = add.ReferenceNumber
group by rln.LastName, add.Address1, add.ZipCode 
having count(rln.LastName) > 1
```

is enough

Comment: Thanks for getting back, that has worked well. Is there a way of amending this to show where there is a duplication between surname, address 1 and zipcode, and then output only the records that have duplication across these three fields? Thanks again.

Comment: you mean the three simultaneously ?

Comment: Yes - to see if a surname, address1 and zipcode are duplicated in more than one record. Also if the output can just show these records. Thanks for getting back.